# Deploying a Spring boot app to the cGoogle cloud

Tags: spring-boot, docker, google-cloud-platform

I created a Spring Boot app that runs a simple process and at the end of that process it creates a CSV file which I need to be able to download. The process spins up a Docker image. The whole process takes about 15 minutes and needs to be run once per day.

I am unsure which 'plan' I should use to run my app so I am looking for suggestions about this.
Thanks in advance!

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I think `Cloud Run` can be a good choice for your use case.

You can deploy your [Spring Boot Service](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/deploy-java-service) with `Cloud Run`.

You can then schedule your `Cloud Run` service with [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/using-scheduler) to be run once per day.

A [Cloud Run service](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/request-timeout) request timeout is set by default to 5 minutes and can be extended up to 60 minutes :

```bash
gcloud run deploy --image IMAGE_URL --timeout=[TIMEOUT]
```

Comment: It seems to me that Cloud Run only accepts containers. My Spring boot app is not containerized. It's not possible to containerize as it spawns a new docker container. You cannot spawn a new container inside a running one.

Comment: The new Docker Container is buit by the Spring Boot app ?

Comment: The Spring boot spawns a testcontainer